# How do you find a village on survival?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My brother and I are playing Minecraft on our phones, but have yet to find a village in survival mode.

We've seen villages in creative but never in survival. How do we find one? What seed could I use to find one ?

Answer (score 3):

1) make sure you have structures turned on in the world settings.

2) villages spawn in specific biomes. Big plains biomes are the best ones to find villages in.

Good luck in searching and sometimes it does take a while to find one, just keep making new worlds if you have no luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not always, but quite often, in [MCPE, villages form on the banks of a river](https://mcpehq.com/faq/find-villages-minecraft-pe/).

If you're playing in survival and come across a river, pick a direction and follow it (or even better make a boat and cruise the river) and you'll eventually find a village.